# js get set with dynamic variables in node-opcua

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-opcua

Examples on node-opcua @ https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua say that I need to rewrite code for every variable added to the OPC server, this is achieved calling 'addressSpace.addVariable()'... But if I have 1000 variables it could be an hard task... and eventually each custom user want a code rewrite, it could be tedious... so I'm trying to do it dynamically.

The opc read 'tags' from another custom server (not OPC).

With this 'tags' the opc server needs to add them to node 'device'.

When the OPC server node-opcua find a get or set of a variable coming from the net, it call the get or set of the correct variable:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tags.GetTags.length; i++)
    {
        variables[tags.GetTags[i].Tag] = {"value" : 0.0, "is_set" : false};

        addressSpace.addVariable({
            componentOf: device, // Parent node
            browseName: tags.GetTags[i].Tag, // Variable name
            dataType: "Double", // Type
            value: {
                get: function () {
                    //console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));
                    return new opcua.Variant({dataType: opcua.DataType.Double, value: variables[this["browseName"]].value }); // WORKS
                },
                set: function (variant) {
                    //console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));
                    variables[this["browseName"]].value = parseFloat(variant.value); // this["browseName"] = UNDEFINED!!!
                    variables[this["browseName"]].is_set = true;
                    return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;
                }
            }
        });

        console.log(tags.GetTags[i].Tag);
    }
```

As I say I tried to use the 'this' in get and set functions with half luck, the get has a 'this.browseName' (the tag name) property that can be used to dynamic read my variables and it currently works.

The problem is with the set, in set 'this.browseName' and 'this.nodeId' don't exist! So it gives 'undefined' error. It also doesn't exist in variant variable.

Do you know a work-around to use dynamic variables with the above code? I need to have one for loop with one get and one set definitions for all variables (tags), that read and write a multi-property object or an array of objects, like 1 get and 1 set definitions that write the right variable in a n records array.

PS: I found on stack overflow this:

`var foo = {
       a: 5,
       b: 6,
       init: function() {
           this.c = this.a + this.b;
           return this;
       }
    }`

But in my case node-opcua Variable doesn't has a 'this' working like the example. In the 'set' (like init): this.browseName (like a) and this.nodeId (like b) are not reachable.

Answer (score 2):

Gotcha,

you need to cast get and set properties as functions like:

```
addressSpace.addVariable({
            componentOf: device,
            browseName: _vars[i].Tag,
            dataType: "Double",
            value: {
                get: CastGetter(i),
                set: CastSetter(i)
            }
        });
```

with

```
function CastGetter(index) {
    return function() {
        return new opcua.Variant({dataType: opcua.DataType.Double, value: opc_vars[index].Value });
    };
}

function CastSetter(index) {
    return function (variant) {
        opc_vars[index].Value = parseFloat(variant.value);
        opc_vars[index].IsSet = true;
        return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;
    };
}
```

you will use an index to get and set values in the array, casting function like this will provide index to be "hard coded" in those get and set properties.